# Decoding WAV file from javascript Blob

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, blob

I am currently working on a web project that uses javascript MediaRecorder to save the audio from a user on a page. I then want to send the audio file (saved as WAV) to my server. Note I am using the Python Flask library as my server backend.

My javascript represents the audio as a Blob as follows:

```
 var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav' });

 // assign blob to data
 data = blob;
```

I then open a socket and send my data to the Python backend as follows:

```
socket.emit('submit_task', data, function() {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                });
```

The data is being received on the backend perfectly fine, and I have tested to make sure that audio WAV file is valid. I now want my server to reconstruct the WAV file from this Blob data and then save it to the disk where my server is running. However, I'm pretty confused how to go about doing this since I am not sure how the WAV file is being encoded in the Blob object. Therefore I'm not too sure what the appropriate decoding scheme is on the backend. Printing the data on the backend just shows random characters that are not easily interpretable. What is a good way to go about getting the WAV file from this Blob data I send to the server?

Thanks!